# What is the proper way to find an 'internal server error 500' in php?

Tags: php, json, internal-server-error

I am continuously having this internal server error to a very simple php code working with JSON. The values I am logging from the code is absolutely correct, yet when in action I am getting an internal server error 500 from this particular code. I had a similar code working previously. What am I doing wrong? or how should I proceed with debugging the error?

```
<?php

$var2 = $_POST['phn'];
$phone_received = json_decode($var2);

$adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

$query1 = "SELECT addressid FROM address WHERE mobile = ?"; 
$leadID = $adb->pquery($query1, array($phone_received));

$row= $adb->num_rows($leadID);

if ($row != 0) {      
    $result = 'This number has already been used in the system.';
    echo json_encode($result); 
}else{
    $result = 'Good to go!';
    echo json_encode($result); 
}    

?>
```

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @FirstOne That doesn't generally help with 500 errors, because those are usually syntax errors that prevent anything in the script from running.

Comment: @Barmar , yes, tried these! did not help. What do you recommend?

Comment: @AbirImtiaz If you didn't see it in the log you must have been looking in the wrong log file.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add `true` parameter to your `json_decode` call? I suppose the problem is with the `$phone_received` param. I also suggest you line by line debugging: try to retrun some dummy result after each line of code step by step so you can detect the place where the error occurs.

Comment: that isn't what the question is about; read it over again.

Comment: I read it correctly and gave my suggestions. What didn't you like about it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, my 1st question was about my code which I shared, so I think this comment helped.